# How do you gradually concatenate strings of previous rows in a pandas groupby dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, window-functions

I am trying to build a text classifier that uses gradually growing conversations as input.

I have a dataset that looks like this:

| conversation_id | message | message_order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "hi I need help" | 1 |
| 1 | "I lost my bags" | 2 |
| 1 | "pls help." | 3 |
| 1 | "thank you." | 4 |
| 2 | "you guys suck" | 1 |
| 2 | "I need a refund" | 2 |

where `conversation_id` is how I am grouping the messages into a conversation and `message_order` is the order in which the messages came in. There are two conversations in this example: the first conversation has 4 messages and the second one has 2.

I want to build a dataframe that looks like this:

| conversation_id | prev_convo | current_message | message_order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | "hi I need help" | 1 |
| 1 | "hi I need help" | "I lost my bags" | 2 |
| 1 | "hi I need help I lost my bags" | "pls help." | 3 |
| 1 | "hi I need help I lost my bags pls help." | "thank you." | 4 |
| 2 | null | "you guys suck" | 1 |
| 2 | "you guys suck" | "I need a refund" | 2 |

Notice though that **prev_convo is a concatenation of EVERY previous message in the conversation up until the current_message, and not just the message right before**.

I think some sort of lag function like pandas `shift()` would work, but I can't get it right.

Answer (score 0):

This can help:

```
df['prev_convo'] = df['prev_convo'].fillna("")
df.groupby("conversation_id")['current_message'].apply(','.join)
```

The output:

```
conversation_id
1    "hi I need help","I lost my bags","pls help.",...
2                    "you guys suck","I need a refund"
Name: current_message, dtype: object
```